# Nothing happening when sending push notification with raix:push

Tags: ios, meteor, push

I am trying to do a push notification from the browser console using raix (version 2.6.1).
I have tried pushing using the php script from [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) and it works with the certificate and key I have, but when I tried it with raix, nothing happen on the phone. I tried doing:

```
Push.send({from: "pushfrom", title:"hello", text:"world", token:{apn: "my_ios_device_token"}});
```

This is my config.push.json

```
{
  "apn": {
    "passphrase": "xxxxxxx",
    "key": "aps_key.pem",
    "cert": "aps_cer.pem"
  }, 
  "badge": true,
  "sound": true,
  "alert": true,
  "vibrate": true
}
```

I have insecure package, but still, I tried adding the Push.allow and it didn't help.

**How do I know whether the notification is actually being pushed to APNS or nothing is happening at all?**

Answer (score 5):

I'll try giving as close to an answer as possible:

Try using the `$ meteor shell` server console to send messages, server doesn't require allow/deny rules for sending (it's a client-side security)

Behind the scenes theres actually two collections:

- Push.notifications - containing the pending notifications to send (these are queued)
- Push.appCollection - This one keeps and maintain the tokens (eg. removes tokens if revoked by gcm/apn services)

So you can use the meteor shell to check if the client app registres a push token - if it does then you should be ready to send a message to it eg. directly via the meteor shell.

If you don't get tokens from the client in the Push.appCollection - then you have a config or certificate issue - that's the hard part of push notifications.

If you get tokens into the `Push.appCollection` then it's prop. something with the server setup. This could be certificates, I've added a guide on the `raix:push` repo for testing server certs. Also think in *ports*, you need to have some ports open for your server to communicate with the gcm/apn service. Also think in firewalls etc. depending on your/client setup and security level on the wifi etc.

Please help out improving documentation on the project - I built the thing and take alot for granted, so there might be a missing clue etc. the documentation.

You can also use the `query: {}` instead of sending to one specific token *(while testing)*

Latest version is at 2.6.6,

Push notifications is besides scrolling the smallest hardest feature to work with.

Kind regards Morten

Comment: RaiX I would like to hire you for some consulting regarding push notifications. Please contact me at ryan (at) ticktbox.com

Comment: I have a similar problem. If I check Push.appCollection in the browser it is undefined. Is this also a Certificate problem or does it only use this collection in a cordova context?